# Alterando tipo de campo MariaDB(Mysql)

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Pessoal criei uma tabela chamada cadastros em um banco de dados teste.
Nele estava fazendo a inserção de dados de um arquivo cadastros.txt

até então a `id primary key` quando criei não era `auto_increment`
então para fins de teste fiz um `drop table` e recriei a tabela com o campo `primary key auto_increment`.

minha duvida é:

o campo `id_faz` é:

`id_faz int unique not null primary key,`

tem como alterar para:

`id_faz int unique not null auto_increment primary key`

sem deletar e recriar uma nova tabela ou sem perder os dados da tabela atual?

A estrutura da tabela é esta abaixo:

```
create table cadastros( 
  `id_faz` int unique not null primary key, 
  `nome_faz` varchar(25) unique not null, 
  `data_compra` date not null 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a query **[ALTER TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/)**.

```
ALTER TABLE incremento CHANGE `id_faz` `id_faz` INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: funcionou legal eu tinha visto esse comando em outro site mas estava dizendo que duplicava os campos..